# Handling large zip files with RubyZip: Limitations with 65535 files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently facing an issue with the RubyZip library while processing large zip files containing hundreds of thousands of files. It seems that RubyZip has a limitation of 65535 files per zip archive.

Is there a recommended approach or alternative solution to efficiently handle and process large zip files with a high number of files using Ruby? Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: The original ZIP format had a limit of 65,535 files but it was later increased via "ZIP64". Make sure that [ZIP64 support](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip#zip64-support) is enabled.

Comment: Awesome @Stefan that worked when creating a new zip with zip64 support, what can I do about zips which are not zip64 like the previous one I had created?

Comment: Why not enable ZIP64 for all zip files?

Comment: I was just wondering in case users send us a zip with no zip64 support but they might have a greater amount of files than 65535.

Comment: If your users want to send more than 65,535 files but are still using compression tools from before 2001 (when ZIP64 was introduced), they might finally have a reason to upgrade ;)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems that RubyZip has a limitation of 65535 files per zip archive

That depends on the format being used. The original Zip format from 1989 had a limit of 65,535 files per archive. A 64-bit variant called "Zip64" was introduced with [version 4.5](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/APPNOTE/APPNOTE-4.5.0.txt) in 2001 which suppports up to 2<sup>64</sup> (minus 1) files.

In RubyZip, [Zip64 support](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip#zip64-support) can be enabled via:

```
Zip.write_zip64_support = true
```

However, according to the docs, it's *enabled* by default. You might have (accidentally?) disabled it explicitly.